# Getting invalid time after adding 3 seconds using dateWithTimeInterval in selected date in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to add 3 seconds in time dynamically.

i.e, **"20-05-2014 3-08-58"** is my selected date. Now i want to add 3 seconds in time like new date is **"20-05-2014 3-09-01"**. I used the following logic for that but its can't work.

`NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];                   [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:strDateTime]
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:3.0 sinceDate:date];`

Using the above logic i got newDate like **"20-05-2014 07-29-01"** which was invalid.

So how to fix this invalid time problem.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: 20-5-2014, formatter should be dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of mistakes in  DateFormatter :

See the corrected solution:

```
NSString *strDateTime = @"20-05-2014 3-08-58";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:strDateTime];
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:3 sinceDate:date];

NSLog(@"cur:%@, next:%@",date,  newDate);
```

***Output:***

> cur:2014-05-19 21:38:58 +0000, next:2014-05-19 21:39:01 +0000

**EDIT:**

As you are expecting the date in your format with +3 seconds, so you need to again convert the NSDate value to NSString.

```
NSString *dateAfter3Sec = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate];

NSLog(@"%@",dateAfter3Sec);
```

It will give you `20-05-2014 03-09-01`

Comment: i integrate like that but still i got invalid date "newDate : 2014-05-19 21:39:10 +0000"

Comment: Yes, but if my date is "20-05-2014 3-08-58" then it should be "20-05-2014 3-09-01".